# Possible to bundle remote assets with ParcelJS

Tags: node.js, webpack, parceljs

Is it possible to bundle external resources linked with absolute URLs to the dist folder with Parcel?

This bundles and hashes fine

`<img src="./image.jpg" />` to `<img src="image.f83j2f.jpg" />`

What i'd like to do

`<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" />` to `<img src="image.f83j2f.jpg" />`

I know this is an expected behaviour but my reasoning is that I want to use an asset CDN like Cloudinary or Uploadcare for the image transformations, then copy them to the build directory.

I'd love to replicate the Gatsby image functionality where transformations are done during build but i cannot find anything to do image transformations locally with Parcel.

Is there something I can trigger externally before the Parcel bundler to download the files to the src and update references to the local file? Any ideas would be much appreciated